Непонятки в type df/series на выходе функции
Основной код:
def spending_by_category(transactions: pd.DataFrame,
                         category: str,
                         date: Optional[str] = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Функция вычисления трат по заданной категории за последние 3 месяца от даты.

    * transactions - DataFrame с транзакциями
    * category - категория, по которой вычисляются траты
    * date - дата, от которой ведется исчисление трат за последние 3 месяца
        ** по умолчанию - сегодня; формат - "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
    """

    if not date:
        true_date = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    else:
        true_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    minus_3_months = true_date - relativedelta(months=3)

    datetime_df = transactions

    datetime_df["Дата операции"] = datetime_df["Дата операции"].apply(
        lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))

    filtered_by_date_df = datetime_df[
        (minus_3_months <= datetime_df["Дата операции"])
        & (datetime_df["Дата операции"] <= true_date)
        ]

    filtered_df = filtered_by_date_df[["Категория", "Сумма операции"]]

    category_df = filtered_df.groupby("Категория", as_index=False)["Сумма операции"].sum()

    result = category_df[category_df["Категория"] == category]

    return result

Если прописывать return type(result), то он четко выдает <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.
Однако PyCharm выделяет result в return и пишет, что это Series, а функция на выходе ожидает pd.DataFrame.
Не заглядывал только в документацию pandas, а ChatGPT и Гугл говорит, что ошибки в коде (с типами данных) быть не должно.

А что насчёт type(transactions)?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

type(transactions) -- <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Версии PyCharm и pandas? У меня ничего не подчеркивает.

...и версию питона еще, на всякий случай

Кстати, в качестве эксперимента, а если аннотацию на выходе функции изменить на pd.Series, будет ругаться?

Это не ответ на вопрос, но попытка избавится от ошибки: написать явную аннотацию после определения result, типа того: result: pd.DataFrame = category_df...

PyCharm 2024.1.4
pandas 2.2.3
python 3.12.8
Если поменять аннотацию, то перестает ругаться
если писать явную аннотацию на result, category_df ругается на все, что после = идет
я конечно result в pd.DataFrame() обернул просто чтоб он не ругался, и результаты и type(result) не меняется, но непонятно что это вообще такое
